# Can't install @angular/cli - Eintegrity err

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I cant install angular Cli. Everytime i got eintegrity error. I spend 3 hours on trying to fix it but i cant. I tried to:

-uninstall node js

-clear cache (with force)

-cache verify

-force installation

-restart computer (ultimate method)

everything in admin mode, no vpn, no work net, disabled antivirus

i tried everything i found in internet. Please help me ;(

edit:
i used force on below, but i have the same problem with no force and not only angular cli. I cant install node modules in new porjects. If i dont have complete node_modules already i always got this error. Always got many "npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open..." and Eintegrity with sha512. I instaled many versions on npm and always is the same.

edit: My mood is much better now becouse my friend show me yarn and everything works right now.

```
            Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.11.4 (x64) and npm.

            C:\Users\Dawid>npm install -g -f @angular/cli@latest
            npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\lazy.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\index.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\auto-bind.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\.lint'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\CHANGES'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c\.travis.yml'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73\math\cosh\implement.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73\math\cosh\index.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73\math\cosh\is-implemented.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73\math\cosh\shim.js'
            npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73\math\expm1'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: form-data@2.3.1 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\form-data):
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sha1-b7lPvXGIUwbXPRXMSX/kzE7NRL8= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-b7lPvXGIUwbXPRXMSX/kzE7NRL8= but got sha1-cwaoKAk10aif5UUfbvycU0fVc+o=. (2235 bytes)
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: json-schema@0.2.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\json-schema):
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sha1-tIDIkuWaLwWVTOcnvT8qTogvnhM= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-tIDIkuWaLwWVTOcnvT8qTogvnhM= but got sha1-aO5Xvx8ASSTgupMMAxQGzuuoBSA=. (10511 bytes)
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: domelementtype@1.3.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\domelementtype):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\domelementtype-5c1c5adb'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: domain-browser@1.1.7 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\domain-browser):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\domain-browser-268370f4'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: extend@3.0.1 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\extend):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\extend-646b29c8'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ee-first@1.1.1 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ee-first):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ee-first-e23bb72b'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: etag@1.8.1 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\etag):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\etag-de690361'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lower-case@1.1.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\lower-case):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\lower-case-1473f9a4'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: d@1.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\d):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\d-633b314c'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: har-validator@5.0.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\har-validator):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\har-validator-271be468'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: macaddress@0.2.8 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\macaddress):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\macaddress-553650c3'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: es6-weak-map@2.0.2 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\es6-weak-map):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es6-weak-map-2432804b'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: mime-db@1.30.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\mime-db):
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sha1-dMZD2i3Z1qRTmZY0ZbJtXKfXHwE= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-dMZD2i3Z1qRTmZY0ZbJtXKfXHwE= but got sha1-dIV2fpdjOEij6vaVp2dkYwo6uC4=. (4996 bytes)
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: glob-parent@2.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\glob-parent):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\glob-parent-c87994bf'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: es5-ext@0.10.35 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\es5-ext):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-56220b73'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: hoek@4.2.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\hoek):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\hoek-ac39987c'
            npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: is-svg@2.1.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\is-svg):
            npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\is-svg-e8b32946'

            npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
            npm ERR! sha512-h5PpgXkWitc38BBMYawTYMWJHFZJVnBquFE57xFpjB8pJFiF6gZ+bU+WyI/yqXiFR5mdLsgYNaPe8uao6Uv9Og== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-h5PpgXkWitc38BBMYawTYMWJHFZJVnBquFE57xFpjB8pJFiF6gZ+bU+WyI/yqXiFR5mdLsgYNaPe8uao6Uv9Og== but got sha512-uUh9//t3qqpwoxIkrBwDoBAab1jurLlefDXZEHigrk9a3K5cPM9P1snG7WDhiSHqjwdQJ10oowj1m055+KEopw==. (2238 bytes)

            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-22T14_21_13_622Z-debug.log

            C:\Users\Dawid>
```

there is log file: 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02743975547384832802

Comment: I cant install anything with npm - update.

Comment: Did you finally find the solution ?

Comment: I remember i just had used Yarn, and it solve problem. Yarn help me many times same way.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the install using an administrator command prompt.